# PHP __DIR__ working locally but not on production

Tags: php, wordpress, fwrite, wordpress-plugin-creation, pantheon

I have a script in a Wordpress plugin and I am trying to incorporate logging using `fwrite()`.

My code is like this:

```
 $log_url =  __DIR__ . '/logs/update-email-publish-tasks/' . date("n.j.Y") . '.txt';
    $logfile = fopen($log_url, "w"); 
    fwrite($logfile, 'Starting tasks at ' . date("H.i.s") . "\n");

//A bunch of code that logs stuff;

    fwrite($logfile, "\n" . 'Finished at !' . date("H.i.s") . "\n");
    fclose($logfile);
```

This is working fine locally but does not work on production. I am wondering if I need to use something besides `__DIR__`? I also tried `WP_CONTENT_DIR` which did not work.

FWIW I am hosting production on Pantheon.

Comment: What "does not work on production" means to you? What exactly is different or wrong?

Comment: No logging occurs, and the script does not run. If I remove all logging it works, so my hypothesis is it has something to do with getting directory while running on a web server as opposed to locally

Comment: The value of `$log_url` in production is a valid path?

Comment: locally, yes. My questions is, is there a reason I should do it differently on production?